# Building multiple github repositories at once

Tags: git, maven, github, maven-release-plugin

I have a multi module SVN project where the complete parent project takes around 2+ hours to build. I have many sub-modules which can be built separately.

```
project-parent
 -project-a
 -project-b
 -project-c
 -pom.xml
```

This means that I can either build `project-parent` as a whole, or the 3 sub-modules separately.

We are moving this project to Github.

We cannot use a single repository as that would mean that `project-a`, `project-b`,`project-c` cannot be checked out and built independently (partial checkouts with git is cumbersome?, we would like to split the project into multiple repositories as it's huge.)

Below is what I want to do.

1. release `project-parent` along with it's sub-modules using the
   maven-release-plugin (a single release build) on jenkins
2. checkout and `project-a`, `project-b`,`project-c` independently
3. Build project-parent` along with it's sub-modules using a jenkins job

What's the best way to distribute such projects on github and build them using maven?

Comment: Exact same requirement I have, were you able to solve this?